# How do I make luakit my default browser?

Tags: default-programs

I tried System Settings -> Details -> Default Applications -> Web but it's not listed as a web browser.

I also tried using update-alternatives, and it's listed there, but setting this doesn't seem to change anything--when I try `gnome-open http://www.something.com` it still opens with firefox.

I also tried changing the gconf settings for /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/ but that doesn't seem to stick.

What can I do to make [luakit](http://mason-larobina.github.com/luakit/) my default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. From a terminal:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/
$ echo "[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Luakit Web Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
GenericName=Web Browser
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Exec=luakit %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=luakit
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;video/webm;application/x-xpinstall;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;" > ~/.local/share/applications/luakit.desktop
$ update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Then in System Settings > Details > Default Applications, you should be able to select `Luakit Web Browser`.